# Using dictionary comprehenion, need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

Consider you have JSON structured like below:

```
{
    "valueA": "2",
    "valueB": [
        {
            "key1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "key2": "value2"
        },
        {
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

and when doing something like:

```
dict_new = {key:value for (key,value) in dict['valueB'] if key == 'key2'}
```

I get:

```
 ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: You're effectively trying to do `key, value = {'key1': 'value1'}`, which won't work.

Comment: I want to be able to take the (key,value) from dict where key =='key2'

Comment: It's can be as a new dictionary or a tuple

Comment: Again, that won't work, you can't unpack dictionary keys and values like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dict['valueB']` is a *list of dictionaries*. You need another layer of nesting for your code to work, and since you are looking for **one** key, you need to produce a list here (keys must be unique in a dictionary):

```
values = [value for d in dict['valueB'] for key, value in d.items() if key == 'key2']
```

If you tried to make a dictionary of `key2: value` pairs, you will only have the last pair left, as the previous `value`s have been replaced by virtue of having been associated with the same key.

Better still, just grab that one key, no need to loop over *all* items if you just wanted that one key:

```
values = [d['key2'] for d in dict['valueB'] if 'key2' in d]
```

This filters on the list of dictionaries in the `dict['valueB']` list; if `'key2'` is a key in that nested dictionary, we extract it.